# Loaded Font Not Displaying in Node.js Project

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, fonts

I'm trying to display a [google font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oswald) in my node.js project. I had to add [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) to load the .ttf file, but it's not displaying. It seems to be loading fine - this is my terminal output:

[image: terminal output]

This is my webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const javascript = {
  test: /\.(js)$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: { presets: ['env'] }
  }],
};

const postcss = {
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
    plugins() { return [autoprefixer({ browsers: 'last 3 versions' })]; }
  }
};

const styles = {
  test: /\.(scss)$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader?sourceMap', postcss, 'sass-loader?sourceMap'])
}; 

const fonts = {
  test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: './public/fonts/'
      }
    }
  ]
}

const uglify = new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: { warnings: false }
});

const config = {
  entry: {
    App: './public/javascripts/app.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [javascript, styles, fonts]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
  ]
};

process.noDeprecation = true;

module.exports = config;
```

The browser shows the font is applied (verified in Chrome and Firefox):
[image: html in browser]

but it is not displaying:

Should be (Android Cordova):
[image: Oswald]

Is:
[image: Not Oswald]

[image: why does it says it's oswald]
Is the browser telling me it's set to Oswald but reverting to a default for some reason?

My CSS:

```
.device {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-display: auto;
    src: url("../fonts/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; 
  }
  h2 {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
...
}
```

I verified the path "../fonts/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf" is correct. E.g. if I change it to ".../fonts/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf" I get a new error.

What am I missing?

Update:
I can get the font to display properly if I add `@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400");` to the end of `@font-face` so I suspect the issue is how the font is being loaded with the webpack config. I'll play with it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `style.css` file is compiled in `public` directory. So, in that case, the path to the font it would be `./fonts/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf`.

Comment: `../fonts/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf` is correct. With `./fonts/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf`, I get the error `ERROR in ./public/sass/style.scss
[���] Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/Oswald-VariableFont_wght.ttf' in ...`

Comment: Could you share a repository with this?

Comment: I appreciate your interest in this, but I'm unable to share this project's repository publicly.

Comment: Then, clone https://github.com/christopher4lis/webpack-fonts-tutorial-complete and see how it works. Good luck.